# Работа с массивами

Tags: c#, массивы, сравнение

Здравствуйте.

Задача такая: пользователь вводит с клавиатуры две строки с числами, например:

```
10 0 31 301 15
01 301 31 105
да
```

Программа должна, не меняя наборы и не создавая новых наборов ответить на вопрос, состоят ли наборы из одних тех же чисел, в том же порядке без учета нулей. Я сделал ввод и преобразование каждого числа в итый элемент массива, но не знаю, как дальше их сравнить без учета нулей. Спасибо.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace L1_T1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            //первая строка
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////
            string[] s1;    // массив строк для разбивки строки на числа
            string s = "";
            int[] Data = new int[100]; // максимальное возможное количество
            int N = 0;    // количество чисел в массиве
            Console.WriteLine("Введите первую строку:");
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            // разбивать строку по пробелам и табуляциям убрав пустые элементы
            s1 = s.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)        // s1[0]=2 s1[1]=4 s1[2]=6
            {
                Data[N] = Convert.ToInt32(s1[i]);
                N++;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Data[i]));
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////
            //вторая строка
            //////////////////////////////////////////

            string r = "";
            int[] Data1 = new int[100]; // максимальное возможное количество
            int M = 0;    // количество чисел в массиве
            Console.WriteLine("Введите вторую строку:");
            r = Console.ReadLine();
            // разбивать строку по пробелам и табуляциям убрав пустые элементы
            s1 = r.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            for (i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)        // s1[0]=2 s1[1]=4 s1[2]=6
            {
                Data1[M] = Convert.ToInt32(s1[i]);
                M++;
            }
            for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(Data1[i]));
            }
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: для начала нужно определиться, что значит "без учета нулей".
Если без учёта ведущих нулей в числе, то они и так обрезаются при преобразовании в Integer, или игнорируя нулевые значения массивов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так. Главная идея заключается в том, чтобы иметь два обходчика. Каждый обходчик игнорирует все символы, кроме цифр. Как только один обходчик встретил цифру, он останавливает свой ход. Когда второй обходчик встречает цифру, две цифры сравниваются. Если они равны, мы их сбрасываем и продолжаем обход, иначе строки не равны, выходим. После того, как обошли обе строки, проверяет, не осталось ли лишних цифр (s1 = "01", s2 = "11"). Если остались, выходим.

Код написан на скорую руку, протестирован на исходном примере и паре примеров попроще. Так что могут быть ошибки, да и наверное попроще можно написать :).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
        string s2 = Console.ReadLine();

        bool result = true;

        char? lastDigit1 = null;
        char? lastDigit2 = null;

        int index1 = 0;
        int index2 = 0;

        while ((index1 < s1.Length) || (index2 < s2.Length))
        {
            // идем, пока строка не кончилась и пока не встретили очередную цифру
            if (index1 < s1.Length && !lastDigit1.HasValue)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(s1[index1]))
                {
                    if (s1[index1] != '0')
                    {
                        // если цифра и не ноль, запоминаем,
                        // в остальных случаях двигаемся дальше
                        lastDigit1 = s1[index1];
                    }
                }
                index1++;
            }

            // идем, пока строка не кончилась и пока не встретили очередную цифру
            if (index2 < s2.Length && !lastDigit2.HasValue)
            {
                if (char.IsDigit(s2[index2]))
                {
                    if (s2[index2] != '0')
                    {
                        // если цифра и не ноль, запоминаем,
                        // в остальных случаях двигаемся дальше
                        lastDigit2 = s2[index2];
                    }
                }
                index2++;
            }

            // если есть две цифры для сравнения
            if (lastDigit1.HasValue && lastDigit2.HasValue)
            {
                if (lastDigit1 == lastDigit2)
                {
                    // цифры равны, продолжаем обход
                    lastDigit1 = null;
                    lastDigit2 = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    // строки не равны, выходим
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // если в результате обхода осталась "лишняя" цифра, то строки тоже не равны
        if (lastDigit1.HasValue != lastDigit2.HasValue)
        {
            result = false;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо). Алгоритм я придумал такой же, только не знал как его реализовать. Я был бы очень признателен, если бы Вы посоветовали мне литературу. Еще раз спасибо!:)

Answer (score 1):

Эх. Учебные задания такие учебные задания.

Такие вещи пишутся в одну строчку на любой функциональщине. Например, LINQ:

```
var c1 = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(Convert.ToInt32);
var c2 = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(Convert.ToInt32);

var equalsIgnoringZeroes = Enumerable.SequenceEqual(
             c1.Where(n => n != 0), c2.Where(n => n != 0));
Console.WriteLine(equalsIgnoringZeroes ? "да" : "нет");
```

(Nitpicker's corner: поскольку у LINQ ленивые вычисления, промежуточные коллекции не материализуются.)

Comment: Хитро. Особенно если это учебное задание, то преподаватель оценит)

Comment: Split() дает промежуточные коллекции :). Но можно и без него на linq'е сделать, сравнивая два сиквенса чаров, а не интов. Вот тогда будет чисто.

Comment: @andreycha: `.Split()` делает непромежуточные коллекции :) То есть именно те самые массивы, которые сравнивает ТС.

Последовательности символов сравнивать можно, но это неуниверсальная хорошая оптимизация: она не сработает, например, для действительных чисел или для сравнения на больше/меньше. Кроме того, не-числа не будут замечены, а это уже плохо.

Comment: Я так понял, что по заданию даны две строки и никаких коллекций промежуточных заводить нельзя.

Comment: @andreycha: Цитирую задание:

> Программа должна, не меняя наборы и не создавая новых наборов ответить на вопрос, состоят ли наборы из одних тех же чисел, в том же порядке без учета нулей.

Это значит, что должны быть наборы _чисел_.